# Can't connect to wifi hotspot

Tags: wireless, 20.04

I set up a wifi hotspot without a password and see that the Wifi Hotspot is active from the menu.

On my android phone I can also see the network. But it just fails if I try to connect to it.

[image]

Is there any way to diagnose what is going wrong?

---

Information requested in a comment:

```
dpkg -l wpa*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version          Architecture Description
+++-==============-================-============-==============================================
un  wpagui         <none>           <none>       (no description available)
ii  wpasupplicant  2:2.9-1ubuntu4.1 amd64        client support for WPA and WPA2 (IEEE 802.11i)
```

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dpkg -l wpa* | grep ii`. Show me the `wifi security` tab.

Comment: @heynnema Added info. Although now I can't see the wifi hotspot at all on my phone. I wonder if there is a driver problem?

Comment: Are you using nm-connection-editor to create your hotspot, or are you choosing "Create wifi hotspot" from the menu? Try setting BAND to 2.4ghz.

Comment: @heynnema I just tried making it with nm-connection-editor. I see Wi-Fi Hotspot Active but I don't see the wifi on my phone (or a laptop nearby). Could it be hidden?  How do I tell that it is working at all?

Comment: Did you set BAND to 2.4Ghz?

Comment: @heynnema That helped in that the network is now visible. But I can't log into it. The signal is also strangely weak given that it is 3 feet away.

Comment: Set Security to **WPA2 Personal** and retry. Make sure your connection settings on the phone/laptop are set to WPA2.

Comment: @heynnema Even with WPA2 Personal  it just refuses to connect. That is it doesn't ask me for a password.

Comment: Try setting Channel to 6.